# Array's content disappearing after using of function that push content into the array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, xml

I'm trying to use at function that push content from xml into the array, I checked it and I see array's content in the function but after the function array's content is disappearing, why? Scope's problem? How I can fix it?
Thanks!

Javascript:

```
<script>
var words = [];
/*var words = [
                                                          {suomen:"puhua", englanti:"to talk", answer:false},
                                                          {suomen:"lukea", englanti:"to read", answer:false},
                                                          {suomen:"kirjoittaa", englanti:"to write", answer:false}
                                                          ];

*/
loadDoc();
alert("The array hasn't content: " + words.toString());

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "catalog.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("WORD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
                             var en =  String(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ENGLISH")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                             var fi =  String(x[i].getElementsByTagName("FINNISH")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                             words.push({suomen:fi, englanti:en, answer:false});
  }
alert("The array has content: " + words.toString());
}
</script>
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
<WORD>
    <FINNISH>puhua</FINNISH>
    <ENGLISH>to talk</ENGLISH>
</WORD>

<WORD>
    <FINNISH>lukea</FINNISH>
    <ENGLISH>to read</ENGLISH>
</WORD>
<WORD>
    <FINNISH>kirjoittaa</FINNISH>
    <ENGLISH>to write</ENGLISH>
</WORD>

</CATALOG>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is `WHY`, so here is an answer: 
myFunction() function is called asynchronously when the response from ajax request has come. So when you call `loadDoc();` and right after call `alert("The array hasn't content: " + words.toString());` - words will be empty because `loadDoc()` need some time to put the data there. 
If you are interested in how to handle that - read more about asynchronous JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

**How to fix**: 
if you need to make a fast fix - just use the code that needs `words` inside the `myFunction()` at the end:

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("WORD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
                             var en =  String(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ENGLISH")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                             var fi =  String(x[i].getElementsByTagName("FINNISH")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                             words.push({suomen:fi, englanti:en, answer:false});
  }
  call_this_function_to_handle_words_array(words)
}
```

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you very much for your help.
I thought about another solution: to use timer of 1 (or 1/2) second before the alert, you think that it'll work well?

Comment: @Motti You could not predict how much time ajax (xhttp) request will take, so it will be not a 100% safety solution. I very recommend you to use that approach that I shared above. In that way, you will be absolutely sure that  `words` array will have values. If I was helpful for you, please, mark my answer as "Answer" and upvote it.  And let me know if I can help you more ;) Thanks